Unable print from Wine after upgrading to 24.04
I recently upgraded to 24.04. I can print from native programs such as LibreOffice, but now I can't print from Quickbooks running in Wine. I have no other programs using Wine.
Error message:
Could not print to printer. Check your printer selection. 
Printing may have been cancelled by another program.

There are no related entries in /var/log/cups/error_log. I have set LogLevel debug2.

I have narrowed down the difference, unsuccessful prints have this"cupsdProcessIPPRequest: requesting-user-name nameWithoutLanguage 'cups-browsed'" successful prints have "cupsdProcessIPPRequest: requesting-user-name nameWithoutLanguage 'mick'

Wine does not supply username
